# Memoization in limited space

Tags: c++, dictionary, memoization, stdmap

While trying to increase the speed for my answer for [this contest](http://www.codechef.com/MARCH13/problems/RDF), I have a function which takes two values `n` and `k` and produces an output. The calculations are repeated, so I'm memoizing it. I can't use a 2D array, since the constraints for `n` and `k` are `10^5`! So I'm using a map:

```
std::map<std::pair<int,int>,double> m;

double solve(int n, int k)
{
    if(k==0) return n;
    if(k==1) return (n-1)/2.0;

    std::pair<int,int> p = std::make_pair(n,k);
    std::map<std::pair<int,int>,double>::iterator it;

    if( (it=m.find(p)) != m.end())
        return it->second;

    double ans = 0;
    for(int i=1 ; i<=n-1 ; i++)
        ans += solve(i,k-1);
    ans = ans/n;
    m[p] = ans;

    return ans;
}
```

But apparently, this approach is way too slow. Is there some problem with my memoization? Or can I get constant time fetches like an array instead of logarithmic fetches from a map?

This function solves this recurrence:

[image: formula]

`f(x,0) = x` and `f(x,1) = (x-1)/2`

Can this be solved in a better way? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: unordered_map would help, but you are doing at least twice more lookups than necessary.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth umm. Apparently in my case..

Comment: @Bruce: I mean, what evidence do you have that this is "too slow"?  Too slow for what?

Comment: What do you want to compute? The general algorithm has more optimization potential than the data structure used for caching.

Comment: I think for this code you'd get a lot more out of analyzing the logic than merely caching the results.  A brief glance makes me think you _should_ be able to calculate this in O(1) instead of the O(n*k) you have here.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm solving a problem. The problem has a recurrence, which this function is solving. But yes, I could be wrong though - there might be a better way to solve that.

Comment: Yes, that could easily be the case - should I add the recurrence to the question, maybe you guys could suggest a better way to solve it?

Comment: @Bruce Yes, please include the recurrence

Comment: @SebastianK I've added it. Please see it.

Comment: Given that `if (k<n-1)` then the result is zero, there's some serious optimization that can be done for those cases.  Also, `map` takes _more_ space than a 2d array for the same data range unless it's sparse, but a quick analysis shows your data won't be sparse.  So either (A) use a 2d array, or (B) only cache _sparcely_.

Comment: @Bruce The recurrence and the code differ. Does i start at 0 or at 1? And what about y < 2? Can I assume this is defined as it is implemented in code?

Comment: @Bruce, recurrence equations need starting conditions and conditions on the variables.

Comment: @SebastianK Yes, that's a tiny mistake there - its 1. These always hold: x>=1, y>=0

Comment: @Bruce Please edit to that effect. Also, clarify the starting conditions outside the code.

Comment: @Bruce f(x, 0) = x, f(x, 1) = x/2 ?

Comment: @SebastianK As you can see in the code, *f(x,0)=x* and *f(x,1)=(x-1)/2*

Comment: For `f(x,y)` when `x or y = 0` what is the results?

Comment: @MatheusOl I've mentioned that already..

Comment: @Bruce, I see... And you could make the life of those willing to help you and add it to the question...

Comment: Just to confirm, for `x=0`, `f(x,y)=0`. Right? Independent of `y`'s value.

Comment: @MatheusOl x>=1 and y>=0 for all cases.

Comment: Because in your code, when it happens, it returns `0.0/0.0`.

Comment: @Bruce I gave an array implementation, The array is backed by std::vector<double>, it should takes less memory than a map using pairs.

Comment: This problem is not a problem on optimization at all, so the dynamic programming tag may not apply.

Answer (score 2):

Minor improvement: Remember the iterator returned by find and dereference it instead of using operator[].

Comment: That's probably quite a major improvement. Lookups in a map are reasonably expensive.

Comment: @us2012 I apologize for that, didn't mean it. I thought it was minor, since SebastianK himself said it was.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Minor, because I guess that a way larger improvement can be achieved by simplifying the recurrence.

Comment: Also cases for k == 0 and k == 1 should not be cached, that does more harm than help.

Comment: @Slava I tried that; I removed those two conditionals and initialized all N's possible in the map with K=0 and K=1. Didn't help..

Comment: @Bruce The other way around. Put the conditionals for k=0 and k=1 before all other stuff in the method and do not cache those values. As Slava mentioned.

Comment: Bruce: Also return 0 for (k < n-1) without caching, as @MooingDuck suggested in the other comment.

Comment: @SebastianK How does that look now?

Comment: @SebastianK I really don't think the result is zero for k<n-1.

Comment: Can you find k < n - 1 with f(k, n) != 0? :)

Comment: @SebastianK f(6,1)=2.5 and f(4,2)=0.3750

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25720/discussion-between-bruce-and-sebastiank)

Comment: @Bruce Oh, you are right. The inequation was wrong. For n < k the result of f(n, k) is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to store a two-dimensional array of values. Instead of memoization, turn the problem around and use dynamic programming instead.

To save some time, note that `f(x, y) = 0` if `x <= y`.

Calculate the values of `f(i, 0)` for `1 <= i <= x - k` and store them into a one-dimensional array. Then calculate `f(i, 1)` for `2 <= i <= x - k + 1`, `f(i, 2)` for `3 <= i <= x - k + 2`, and so on, until you get `f(i, k - 1)` for `k <= i <= x - 1`. Then you can calculate `f(x, k)`. At each step, you only need two arrays of length `x - k`.

Calculating `f(i, j)` takes `i - j - 1` additions and a division. so the total time is ϴ((x - k)<sup>2</sup> k). But it's faster if you compute the sums first and then divide, because each sum is just one element more than the previous, so then the total time is ϴ((x - k) k).

Comment: I think this is a _lot_ more additions than you claim, in fact, I think it's i*k additions and divisions.